# Can we execute an .hql file directly from pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hql

I could run a hive query from pyspark and also could read each line from the .hql file and run the query. But, I want to run the .hql file directly from the pyspark program. I tried searching the internet but couldnt find a solution.

I just wanted to know whether I can run the hql file like I normally with

```
hive -f "hql_file.hql"
```

or spark doesnt provide such kind of solution?

so far I could go with and this works:
I havent added the libraries here..The following code works with retrieving each line from the hql file

```
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
hc=HiveContext(sc)

with open("hql_file_path","r+") as fr:
 for query in fr:
  result=hc.hql(query)
  print result.collect()
```

Comment: Nice try. But you don't have a valid command parser yet. You must locate the command separator `;` (except when it is quoted or escaped) to be able to build individual commands, then locate and replace variables (if any), then submit the commands sequentially. Also you must decide what you do in case of error -- continue or abort?

Comment: yeah.. presently I am reading each query line by line. Googled this but didn't find any solution and now i got the answer. Thanks :)